# Substituting Variable' values in Python during function call.

Tags: python, function

In my python program, I have to call a function like this one:

```
driver_name.project.paired_config_L1_M_10g()
```

What function I call depends on the value that I have stored in three variables, namely:

```
varA == M 
varB == L1 
varC = 10g
```

`varA`, `varB`, and `varC` can have about 20 different values each, and I don't want to write a function call for each one of them (Albeit the actual function definition exists.) Typically I want to function call to be:

```
driver_name.project.paired_config_$varA_$varB_$varC()
```

But this does not seem to work. Suggestions?

Comment: Does this object really have 8000 methods on it? It looks like these methods should just be 1 method that takes 3 arguments.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `getattr`. It takes object and attribute name as a string and returns the attribute. Here the returned value is a method, that could be immediately called.

```
getattr(driver_name.project, 'project_config_%s_%s_%s' % (varA, varB, varC))()
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered a dictionary as one possible solution?

Just initialize the dictionary with the proper keys (varA,varB,varC) and the define functions. Then call it.

```
driver_func_dict['ML110g'] = driver_name.project.paired_config_M_L1_10g
#init more dictionary items here
...

#call function
driver_funct_dict[str(varA)+str(varB)+str(varC)]()
```